# SPI slave read data into buffer on stm32?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32, spi

I'm trying to set communication between esp32 (master) and stm32 (slave) over SPI. esp32 is running under micropython and sends four bytes, for example
`spi.write_readinto(b'\x31\x32\x33\x34', buf)`

stm32' code is here  (instead of this i use `SPI_InitDef.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;`)

```
void SPI_Init(void) {
    ...

    //  initialize SPI slave
    // for slave, no need to define SPI_BaudRatePrescaler
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Slave;
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b; // 8-bit transactions
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB; // MSB first
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low; // CPOL = 0, clock idle low
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge; // CPHA = 1
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Hard; // use hardware SS
    SPI_InitDef.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_64; // APB2 72/64 = 1.125 MHz

    SPI_InitDef.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
    SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitDef);

    SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);
    //Тут мы разрешаем прерывание по приему
    SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI1, SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
}

void main() {
    /* Setup SysTick Timer for 10ms interrupts  */
    if (SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 100))
    {
    /* Capture error */
    while (1);
    }
    /* Configure the SysTick handler priority */
    NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0x0);

    SPI_Init();

    while(1) {
        while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE));
        for (u8 i=0; i<4; i++) {
            printf("0x%02x ", SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1));
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
```

But when I send four bytes `0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34` (analyzer confirms bytes were sent) and my stm gets only `0x31 0x32 0x31 0x32`

**UPD**
 I use std periph library and SPI_I2S_ReceiveData is a native method to read byte from SPI.

```
uint16_t SPI_I2S_ReceiveData    (   SPI_TypeDef *   SPIx     )  
Returns the most recent received data by the SPIx/I2Sx peripheral.

Parameters:
SPIx,:  To select the SPIx/I2Sx peripheral, where x can be: 1, 2 or 3 in SPI mode or 2 or 3 in I2S mode or I2Sxext for I2S full duplex mode.
Return values:
The     value of the received data.

uint16_t SPI_I2S_ReceiveData    (   SPI_TypeDef *   SPIx     )  
Returns the most recent received data by the SPIx/I2Sx peripheral.

Parameters:
SPIx,:  To select the SPIx/I2Sx peripheral, where x can be: 1, 2 or 3 in SPI mode or 2 or 3 in I2S mode or I2Sxext for I2S full duplex mode.
Return values:
The     value of the received data.
```

But maybe I exit out from IRQ before all data are read. I found to run the while loop until the transmission of the last byte is complete

Comment: Side note - you should avoid printing the debug outputs from within the transaction. The debug info channel might stall your SPI transaction, losing the data.

Comment: Probably there is a reason why it works unexpectedly. Thank you, i'll try

Comment: Please include the code here, on this site.

Comment: About your edit: I don't see why you are talking about interrupt. Your code is working in polling not in interrupt (or may be I missed something).

Comment: "I found to run the while loop until the transmission of the last byte is complete" What does it mean ? The only way to know that the reception if complete is to poll for flag EOT with the setup I described. RXNE does not tell you that a reception is complete, only that one byte (or word) is available.

Comment: Seems printf was blocking the order of bytes, now I get all bytes were sent, but since the 2nd and 3rd attempts I see a wrong order
`0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef`
`0xde 0xde 0xad 0xbe` 
`0xef 0xde 0xad 0xbe` 
`0xef 0xde 0xad 0xbe`
`0xef 0xde 0xad 0xbe` 
`0xef 0xde 0xad 0xbe`

Comment: Sure, printf can be pretty long to execute on a MCU (compared to typical durations of SPI communication). But even without printf, the code looks wrong to me as explained in my answer. Did you try what I proposed ?

Comment: Thank you @Guillaume ! I found the reason, when my code is interrupted I send 1 byte and read byte, but `SPI_I2S_ReceiveData` seems to have its own byte transfer and I don't need to call sendData before read. So I remove it and got it working.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Since several persons have spent time to help you, it would be nice to clarify.

Comment: My `SPI1_IRQHandler` uses for loop for reading 4 bytes of data. something like `RxBuf[I++] = SPI_READ();` and `SPI_READ()` function has only 2 lines, the first one is waiting until RXNE would be set and after that `return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code is not correct (but I don't know what the function `SPI_I2S_ReceiveData` is doing):

```
while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE));
for (u8 i=0; i<4; i++) {
  printf("0x%02x ", SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1));
}
```

You exit from the `while` as soon as one byte is ready to be read.  I assume `SPI_I2S_ReceiveData` is only reading the SPI FIFO. in that case you try to read 4 bytes when possibly only one or two has been received.

You didn't precise the kind of STM32 you're using so I am describing the SPI of STM32H7 (as far as I know it should be pretty similar in other STM32).

To setup a reception in slave mode you should define in particular these 3 parameters:

- the length of the socalled "frame" (number of bytes to be read/written at once). This is the field  SPI_DataSize` in the HAL data structure, here 8 bits.
- the number of transfer (TSIZE) which specifies when the End Of Transmission event is generated. It is expressed in number of "frames". This parameter must be set through register SPI.CR2 before each reception (provided you know the number of bytes to be received of course).
- the "FIFO threshold". It specifies at which frequency an event RXP or TXP is generated. You can change this parameter to decrease the workload on the software but to receive only 4 bytes it has no impact.

In your case I think you should setup a transfer size of 4 (4 bytes) and wait for EOT flag to be set. When it is set you only have to read 4 bytes from SPI Receive Register (you can read all 4 bytes at once by the way).

I suggest you do not use the HAL but write your own SPI reception / transmission routines by reading / writing registers. It is not a very complex peripheral (so it will not cost you a lot of time) and you will understand precisely how it works (instead of digging into the HAL).